# How to set the working directory to the current folder?

Tags: r

I wrote code to clean some data that I need to send to a colleague, how do I set a wd that will work for my colleague without them having to change it? They will have the raw data in the same folder as the code file. I think if I can set the wd to be whatever folder the code file is in it would work.

Comment: See the function `setwd`. However, I recommend to write code relative to where the data is (independently if you use here or not).